# Perform Math addition between CSS Variable and SCSS Variable

Tags: css, sass

How to perform addition between CSS variable and SCSS variable?

For example, I have these values:

```
--header-size: 10rem
```

```
$bar-size: 20rem
```

where if combined, the total would be:

```
.gap {
  top: var(--header-size) + $bar-size;       // to be, if possible, 30rem;
}
```

Is this possible? If not, is there a way I can perform addition between them?

Though I do understand that it can be accomplished if both of them are of scss variables but in the current project, there's this scenario where only the css variable is being changed when met with specific breakpoints.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried CSS calc()... more on that here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) and SASS [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
calc(var(--header-size) + #{$bar-size});
```